# Searching for multiple files and changing file extension

Tags: files, filenames

I want to search and identify multiple files, within a directory, having a particular file extension (.txt) and changing the extension to (.fasta). This is considering not changing the file itself, only the extension, and saving it with the new extension.

```
file1.txt --> file1.fasta
file3.txt --> file2.fasta
file3.txt --> file3.fasta
```

Comment: The other question did NOT work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy using a simple `for` loop in the shell.

```
for f in *.txt; do
    mv "$f" "${f%.*}.fasta"
done
```

The `${f%.*}` expands to the filename without the extension.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly! Can you explain what the (mv "$f" "${f%.*}.fasta") part is actually doing?

Comment: @macam `${f%.*}` is the filename without the extension. It simply moves the file to the filename without the extension with ".fasta" appended to the end. See [BashFAQ 73](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073).